# migrate hbase 0.94 to 0.98 - Incompatible Result object for TableMapReduceUtil

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I was using following API from org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil with hadoop 1 and hbase 0.94

```
public static void initTableMapperJob(List<Scan> scans,
      Class<? extends TableMapper> mapper,
      Class<? extends WritableComparable> outputKeyClass,
      Class<? extends Writable> outputValueClass, Job job) throws IOException {
    initTableMapperJob(scans, mapper, outputKeyClass, outputValueClass, job,
        true);
  }

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(scans, Stage1Mapper.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class,  Result.class, job);
```

Now it's giving me compile error with hadoop 2 and hbase 0.98 . I think it's mainly hbase 0.98 that has issue. error is:

`The method initTableMapperJob(List<Scan>, Class<? extends TableMapper>, Class<? extends WritableComparable>, Class<? extends Writable>, Job) in the type TableMapReduceUtil is not applicable for the arguments (List<Scan>, Class<PlanStage1Mapper>, Class<ImmutableBytesWritable>, Class<Result>, Job)`

With hbase 0.98 Result class no longer implements Writable interface and initTableMapperJob expect something that implements Writable. Is there any better alternative to fix this?